# Mule:Generating a template based pdf on a file outbound connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am having this requirement of consuming files from inbound and then applying a template on that data and then generate a pdf file on an outbound connector. Which component do i need to use to apply template and write data as per template in a pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing out of the box for generating a PDF. You could create a custom transformer or component using Apache FOP that can use xsl-fo templates for generating PDFs for example.

Here is an old transformer created for Apache FOP that you could use for inspiration:
https://github.com/muleforge/Apache-FOP

And someone has started a module that may be of use:

https://bitbucket.org/trafacz/apache-fop-mule-module-transformer

Comment: Thanks @Ryan but  what is this Parse template transformer used for . Will this transformer be of any help for me in generating data as per a predefined format.

Comment: No. Only for text based formats really, like text/html etc. It basically allows you to embed Mule expression within a file for templating of variable values etc. Example here:http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Parse+Template+Reference